# using lapply on a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I created a list of dataframes called "list" and want to select only certain columns of every dataset in the list.

```
library(dplyr)
new_list <- lapply(list, select(list, Date))
```

It returns an error because class(list[1]) is not dataframe but still a list. class(list[[1]]) is dataframe. I don't understand that because the elements in my list should be dataframes and I also don't know how I can use "lapply" anyway.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your syntax is just a little off. Try using an anonymous function instead:

```
l <- list(mtcars,mtcars)
lapply(l,function(x) select(x,cyl,mpg))
```

Comment: It looks like you can also pass the column names as arguments to `select` through `lapply`, `lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), select, cyl, mpg)`.

Answer (score 3):

Also worth bearing in mind `[` is a function in itself, so:

```
new_list <- lapply(list, '[', c("list", "Date"))
```